# Windows command prompt (Dos) copies all the files that start with the specified file name

Tags: dos, command-prompt

In Dos if you type

```
copy c:\a.txt
```

it will copy a.txt* (a.txt1, a.txtb, etc)

how can I just copy a.txt?

Comment: Flagged to close this and move it to SuperUser.

Comment: Also, your copy syntax doesn't work.  That will **not** copy a.txt*.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: Why do you think this simple copy command doesn't work?

Comment: Because I tried it and got the error `The file cannot be copied onto itself`.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: If copy command has only one argument it will copy that file to the current directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not correct - `copy c:\a.txt` will only copy the single file to the current directory. It will ignore the other files like `a.txt1` and `a.txtb`.

You must have tried `copy c:\*.txt` - that will copy all forms because the pattern matching searches both long and short (8.3) names.

You can eliminate the problem by using FINDSTR:

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %F in ('dir /b /a-d c:\*.txt^|findstr /eli ".txt"') do @copy "c:\%F"
```

Comment: The problem was I mistyped and used a / instead of a \ before the file name: c:\forler1\folder2/filename.txt, but I leaned a lot from your "for" command.